# Get complexTypes or parameters from WSDL file

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl, echosign

How to get complex types from WSDL file programatically?

I have to get complex types from Adobe echo sign.
https://secure.echosign.com/services/EchoSignDocumentService19?wsdl

There are already some questions on this topic but none has useful answer. So, I am invoking this question again.

This is the code I have written, but no luck.

```
public class wsdlReader {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            WSDLFactory factory = WSDLFactory.newInstance();
            WSDLReader reader = factory.newWSDLReader();

            reader.setFeature("javax.wsdl.verbose", false);
            reader.setFeature("javax.wsdl.importDocuments", true);
            Definition def = reader.readWSDL(null, "https://secure.echosign.com/services/EchoSignDocumentService19?wsdl");
            Map services = def.getServices();
            Iterator servicesIterator = services.values().iterator();
            def.getTypes();
            while (servicesIterator.hasNext()) 
            {
                Service service = (Service) servicesIterator.next();
                Map ports = service.getPorts();
                Iterator portsIterator = ports.keySet().iterator();
                while (portsIterator.hasNext())
                {
                    String strPort = portsIterator.next().toString();
                    Port port = service.getPort(strPort);
                    Binding binding = port.getBinding();
                    PortType portType = binding.getPortType();

                    List operations = portType.getOperations();
                    Iterator opIterator = operations.iterator();

                    while (opIterator.hasNext()) 
                    {
                        Operation operation = (Operation) opIterator.next();
                        if (!operation.isUndefined()) 
                        {
                            Input inDef = operation.getInput();
                            Map params = operation.getInput().getMessage().getParts();
                            Iterator paramsIterator = params.keySet().iterator();
                            int n = 1;
                            StringBuffer sbParams = new StringBuffer();
                            while (paramsIterator.hasNext())
                            {
                                PartImpl iParam = (PartImpl) params.get(paramsIterator.next());
                                if (iParam.getTypeName() == null) {
                                    sbParams.append(iParam.getElementName().getLocalPart()).append(" p").append(n).append(",");
                                    n++;
                                } else if (iParam.getElementName() == null) {
                                    sbParams.append(iParam.getTypeName().getLocalPart()).append(" ").append(iParam.getName()).append(", ");
                                } else {
                                    System.err.println("sicis .:.");
                                }
                            }
                            System.out.println(sbParams);
                            if (sbParams.length() > 0) {
                                sbParams.delete(sbParams.length() - 1, sbParams.length());
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (WSDLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Any help or suggestion will be really helpful.

Thanks

Comment: Why aren't you using the "wsdl2java" (wsimport) tool from the jdk for this? Or alternatively the one in xmlbeans. It generates automatically all classes (from wsdl to xml schema definitions including the complex types).